# Using Google Analytics with a Third-Party Checkout (Magento)

Tags: magento, google-analytics

We currently have a Drupal site that is content-focused and are using Google Analytics for metrics. We are partnered with a company that has a Magento site and cart and will be using them for eCommerce. How do I successfully add our GA tracking code to their domain and cart pages to ensure I am tracking conversions from acquisition to checkout success (or dropout)?

Is it just the simple cross-domain code outlined in the Google knowledgebase?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, should be as simple as cross-domain tracking. Your best bet would be to setup a staging/dev environment to test things out and then push to production.

You can use tools to monitor the http requests getting sent to the server to make sure your tracking is working.

For Firefox, I use [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) and for Chrome it's Google's homegrown [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en).

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was the answer, but I really wanted external confirmation.